# "Not an answer" allows double flagging?

Tags: support, flags, flag-dialog

I just flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122781/exception-oledb-in-vb-net-when-connecting-with-ms-access/20122829#20122829) answer as not an answer:

> [image]

But the Flag "it is not an answer" option is still available:

> [image]

I was expecting something like this:

> [image]

Comment: The option is still there but if you try to flag it, it will say _you already flagged this for moderator attention_.  The option doesn't disappear because you already flagged as not an answer.

Comment: Note that this behaviour is unlike the "recommend closure" flags where it will say "you have already raised this type of flag" and disable the radio button for it.

Comment: And *again* different from the vote-to-close dialog where it says "You have already voted to close this question" and disables all of it except the retract button.

Answer (score 7):

It actually doesn't - I flag NAA's quite often and have bumped into this recently - You get the Red Box of Doom ©:

[image: you have already flagged this post for moderator attention]

I do remember that before, the option would be disabled with '*you have already flagged this post*' or something like that. That would be better - can we have it back?

Comment: I thought it was red ;)

Comment: FWIW, that particular error message only means you currently have a *pending flag* on the post. It's telling you that you can't cast a second flag on the post - you can only have one active at a time. I believe once that "not an answer" flag actually gets *handled*, then the red text will start appearing on the flag dialog (not sure, I can't reproduce this myself since I don't flag).

Comment: @animuson It would be useless at that point. If the flag gest handled and the answer deleted, low rep users(me) can't access the dialogue anymore. Deleted answers are not suitable for our young gentle eyes